# How to use smarty code in PHP file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smarty

I'm appending a table row to the HTML table in smarty template by using AJAX. It's working perfect for me except a small thing. I'm not able to integrate smarty code in this ajax response. Following is the AJAX response from PHP file.

```
echo "<tr id='reb$rebate_no'><td><input type='text' name='pack[]' value='' class='form-control' size='8'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='quantity[]' value='2' class='form-control' size='8'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='volume[]' value='750' class='form-control' size='8'/></td>
      <td><div class='btn-group'><select id='unit' name='units[]' class='form-control'><option value='' {if $data.id==''} selected='selected'{/if}>Select Unit</option>
      {foreach from=$all_volume_units item=units key=key}<option value='{$units.id}' {if $units.id == $data.units[$units]} selected='selected'{/if}>{$units.unit}</option>
      {/foreach}</select></div></td><td><input type='text' name='amount[]' value='3.00' class='form-control' size='9'/></td></tr>";
```

The above code is giving error. But I want to include the smarty code or to replace the smarty code by PHP code. How should I achieve this?

Comment: "The above code is giving error" - can you please share the error that you are getting?

Comment: @SoftwareGuy:The page is getting blank.

Comment: You really, really, should read Smarty documentation (http://www.smarty.net/documentation), that would solve most of the questions you post here about Smarty, what it is, how it's used and how template engines are supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

I think, smarty is not designed for such usage, because it first compiles the string into php code. However it is possible to use string resource, but whenever string is changed new php file is created. double quotes should not be used to enclose string, PHP will recognize words starting with dollar sign as variables.

more information on using string resources, is here;
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl

Comment: ok then can you provide me the same functionality using PHP code instead of smarty code?

Comment: $str = '<select id="unit" name="units[]" class="form-control">';
$id = 12;
foreach ($unit_list as $key => $unit) {
   $selected = ($key == $id) ?'selected="selected' : '';
   $str .= "<option value='$key' $selected >$unit</option>";
}
$str .= '</select>';
echo $str;